# broken search field of python-sphinx website on reathedocs.org

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I discovered that the search function of the latest version of my website
**eswp3.org** hosted on readthedocs.org does not work anymore. I use the default
search functionality of the python-sphinx html theme *sphinx_rtd_theme*. I use the default makefile to build the html files.

Some possible bug cause investigation:

- The search field of website versions v1.1 and website version v1.0 is broken.
- In website version V0.1 the search field is working. (Versions may be switched
  with the field in the bottom left on the website.)
- After rebuilding the [website sources v1.0](https://github.com/fkromer/eswp3/releases/tag/v1.0) and on the local file system the
  search field of v1.0 does not work, the search field of v0.1 does work.
- Comparing the website source v1.0 and v0.1 lead to following differences:

[To the diff screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKxJq.png)

- I checked the differences in conf.py but i did not catch critical differences.
- I deleted the files in _build/html and rebuilt the files with the
  python-sphinx default make target `make html` in the root directory eswp3/ on
  my local file system. No problems regarding indexing have been printed.
- Unfortunately the search field in the generated version is also not working.

What did i miss? Do i have to consider possible differences of the python-sphinx versions used in the different builds?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some files edited on windows machines have not been commited to github as UTF-8 format files but WINDOWS-1252 format files initially or after file edits. Converting all *.rst files to UTF-8 did the job (e.g. by converting  all *.srt files of the current directory on UNIX into a subfolder /utf-8 using `find . -name "*.rst" -exec iconv -f WINDOWS-1252 -t UTF-8 {} -o utf-8/{} \;`).

Answer (score 0):

Modify the following code in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sphinx_rtd_theme\layout.html`

**Unfixed:**

```
164 <script type="text/javascript">
165 var DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS = {
166    URL_ROOT:'{{ url_root }}',
167    VERSION:'{{ release|e }}',
168    COLLAPSE_INDEX:false,
169    FILE_SUFFIX:'{{ '' if no_search_suffix else file_suffix }}',
170    HAS_SOURCE:  {{ has_source|lower }}
171 };
```

**Fixed:**

```
164 <script type="text/javascript">
165 var DOCUMENTATION_OPTIONS = {
166    URL_ROOT:'{{ url_root }}',
167    VERSION:'{{ release|e }}',
168    COLLAPSE_INDEX:false,
169    FILE_SUFFIX:'{{ '' if no_search_suffix else file_suffix }}',
170    HAS_SOURCE:  {{ has_source|lower }},
171    SOURCELINK_SUFFIX: '{{ sourcelink_suffix }}'
172 };
```